# Grafcet - synchronous machine behaviour

Tags: parallel-processing, sequential, plc

My goal is to implement a control algorithm written in Grafcet on a PLC. I am struggling with the difference of Grafcet as multi-process synchronous language and the single-core sequential PLC. Below is an example. What is the outcome of the Grafcet in the first cycle after the upper transition has fired? `(a=1,x=1)` or `(a=1, x=0)`? 
I know that in SFC, it depends on the implementation of the engineering tool (e.g. Codesys, Multiprog) how actions are evaluated, typically from left to right. So for an SFC, `(a=1,x=1)` would be the answer. But since everything happens at the same time in Grafcet, I do not know how to handle this case. 
[image]
Bonus points if someone can point out how I can learn more about the challenges of implementing languages like Grafcet on sequential machines.

Answer (score 1):

*Conditional actions* are considered in **not all** Grafcet variants, but when they are, the behavior goes like this: *as long as the step is active, turn on `x` while `a` is on*.
If that's what you meant, though we may never find a conditional action formatted the way you did, `x` will be turned on *within an infinitely short time* after the two simultaneous steps are activated (at least that's my understanding based on the Grafcet evolution rules). So, the fact that the initial value of `x` is unpredictable - assuming that the two concurrent steps are activated *at the very same time* - should be actually no problem.

Moreover, as soon as the Grafcet is "implemented" in the real world (i.e. your single-core PLC), whether it's directly compiled by the engineering tool or converted into ladder diagram, an order of evaluation is *necessarily* chosen, as you said, and everything becomes deterministic, so your question is not a real problem when it comes to "implementing languages like Grafcet on sequential machines". You may find which are the *real* "challanges" by studying the canonical procedure for converting SFCs to ladder logic (detailed documentation is easily found on the web).

Comment: Actually it's great that things happen serially in practice, it helps prevent unpredictable "race conditions" that used to plague hard wired logic.

Answer (score 1):

PLC's are single core, as you said, so... never 2 steps in the same moment of time.

There you have simultaneous branch, so both steps WILL execute. But clearly there will be one after another. By default, always the one from left. Please note that some PLC's allow you to change the order (never tried for simultaneous, but for divergent surely allow... such as RSLogix5000).

Simultaneous it's like having an AND. So you are telling processor execute first step AND second step. If you are familiar with Ladder Logic, I am sure this will be clear to you.
In the end, it should be a=1;x=1.

Also note that for other steps that are not simultaneous, there is one scan delay before evaluate next transition, which is a great thing. This is the most omitted thing when implementing a SFC in Ladder (and can lead to problems impossible to troubleshoot if you are not aware of it). I've seen this "bug" in about 50% of projects with ladder implementation and hundreds of projects so far. Example: If you have 10 consecutive transitions true, you are going from step 1 to step 10 in a single scan. Troubleshoot why motor didn't start :)

Tip: You can always use dummy steps in simultaneous branches to delay with 1 scan. So, if you want the other outcome (a=1,x=0), you can put a dummy step before left step.